# Translating model attribute name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to translate an attribute name in Rails (3.2) to something more human readable, specifically for error messages, but I keep getting the original DB column name. Here's my en.yml file

```
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        encrypted_password: "Password"

    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            encrypted_password: 
                blank: "can't be blank"
```

I also tried this as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812774/how-can-i-translate-the-activerecord-attribute-name-in-rails-3-2)

```
activerecord:
    models:
      user: Dude
    attributes:
      user:
        encrypted_password: "Password"
```

The interesting thing is that the second translation (for errors) works, but not the first. What am I missing ?